# How To Download Image by WebClient

Tags: vb.net, caching, webclient, picturebox

I can download a pic by webclient and successfully paint on picture box. But my question is how can i avoid re download the same image from the net using the cache system. But i don't want to save it to my herd disk.

My code is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim wc As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim ImageInBytes() As Byte = wc.DownloadData(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim ImageStream As New IO.MemoryStream(ImageInBytes)

    PictureBox1.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(ImageStream)
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not store it in the application's main form for as long as the app is running?

Comment: It's because I have to use the same url many times. if I download the pic, I have to download it again. I just want to download the file one time nd if I further need the picture,webclient get the picture from cache instead of downloading the picture again.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I belive WebClient dont support the use of cache.

You could try check the image size, if its diferent download, otherwise use the one you already downloaded.

This code will get the image size, without downloading it:

```
Dim wc As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient
wc.OpenRead("http://example.com/ex.png")
Dim bytes_total As Int64 = Convert.ToInt64(wc.ResponseHeaders("Content-Length"))
```

Comment: no ithink webclient support cache plolicy I.e webclient.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache)